# On Default template Function Parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I want to design a set of functions, such as `min`, `max` and `stddev`, which can support user-defined types. What I plan to do is to let the user pass an `Extractor` template argument to these functions. Some sample code as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct DefaultExtractor
{
  typedef T value_type;
  static T value(T &v){
    return v;
  }
};

template <
  typename Extractor=DefaultExtractor<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>, //error
  typename InputIterator>
typename Extractor::value_type 
foo(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
  return Extractor::value(*first);
}
```

This does not compile and the error message is "error: ‘InputIterator’ was not declared in this scope" on the line of `typename Extractor=...`.

The reason that I want to put the template `Extractor` before `InputIterator` is that, when users want to call `foo` with a customized `Extractor`, they don't need to explicitly provide the type of `InputIterator`.

I wonder whether there is a solution to make the code compile, and at the same time it does not require users to provide the parameter `InputIterator` explicitly when customized `Extractor` is needed.

The code is compiled with `g++-4.6.1 -std=c++0x`.

Comment: If you want to use a default template argument, all template parameters that follow it must also have a default argument. The only exception are C++11 template packs.

Comment: That's not the issue here actually. If I change the default parameter to `DefaultExtractor<float>`, then it compiles. C++11 (n3337) 14.1/11: "A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be
followed by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced or has a default
argument (14.8.2)"

Comment: I referred to §14.1/11: _If a template-parameter of a class template or alias template has a default template-argument, each subsequent template-parameter shall either have a default template-argument supplied or be a template parameter pack._ But you are right, with `float` it compiles. I'd have thought that is against the Standard.

Comment: Ah... it's because yours is a function template, not a class template. Interesting that there is a difference when it comes to how default arguments can be used.

Comment: Exactly. Please notice the "... unless that template parameter can be deduced ...", which actually refers to function templates. BTW: maybe we are referring to different version of the c++11 standard draft.

Comment: Hmm.. actually your quote refers to template packs. You don't use a template pack.

Comment: About the C++11 Standard: I use an official copy of the final version, not a draft. But anyway, I think using default arguments the way you do it (in a function template!) is ok (although not because of the quote you gave, because that's about template packs). The rule I had in mind is only valid for class templates it seems. But still the original problem remains: How can we use `InputIterator` in a default argument, although `InputIterator` is declared later. Still thinking about that.

Answer (score 3):

Although I see that you would like to pass the extractor as a template parameter, it is actually more typical to pass an object to the function.  It is also more flexible, because it allows you to have extra state that can be passed to the extractor.

Most importantly, it makes it easier to handle the template parameters:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
struct DefaultExtractor
{
  typedef T value_type;
  static T value(T &v){
    return v;
  }
};

struct MyExtractor {
  typedef int value_type;
  static int value(int value) { return value; }
};

template <typename Extractor, typename InputIterator>
inline typename Extractor::value_type
foo(
  InputIterator first,
  InputIterator last,
  const Extractor &extractor
)
{
  return extractor.value(*first);
}

template <typename InputIterator>
inline typename DefaultExtractor<
  typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
>::value_type
foo(
  InputIterator first,
  InputIterator last
)
{
  typedef DefaultExtractor<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type> Extractor;
  return foo(first,last,Extractor());
}


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  std::list<int> l;

  // Use default extractor
  foo(l.begin(),l.end());

  // Use custom exractor.
  foo(l.begin(),l.end(),MyExtractor());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Actually I considered this before and thought that passing it as template parameter should be a bit more efficient. I shall use this, if no better solution for the template parameter version.

Comment: @DanqiWang: If you make the function inline, you shouldn't really see any performance difference.  If the function is large enough that you don't want to make it inline, then the overhead of passing the extra parameter should be minimal.  The actual extraction call will be inlined regardless.